# *ngIf - how to do the null check in template

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-observable

I am getting `boolean` value from observable. I am trying to print that. But nothing get print for me.

here is my subscribe:

```
showLeftNavi$: boolean;

    constructor(private store: Store<StateShared>) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.store.pipe(select(ObservableActions.getNaviState)).subscribe(data => {
            console.log('data', data); //getting true
            this.showLeftNavi$ = data;
        });
    }
```

here is my template:

```
<div *ngIf="($showLeftNavi | async) !== 'null'">
    soo {{ $showLeftNavi }} //nothing prints here.
</div>
```

so how to check the null here and print my `Boolean` value?

Comment: Which side are you putting the dollar on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need `async` pipe since `showLeftNavi` is not observable or promise.

> The async pipe subscribes to an Observable or Promise and returns the
>   latest value it has emitted
>   https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

```
<div *ngIf="showLeftNavi$">
    soo {{ showLeftNavi$ }} //nothing prints here.
</div>
```

At one place you are using `showLeftNavi$` and in another place you are using `$showLeftNavi`.

Comment: the problem here is, I will get both true and false. according to you it shows only on true, I would like to print both true and false

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `*ngIf="($showLeftNavi | async) !== 'null'"` try just `*ngIf="$showLeftNavi | async"`

That said, your variable `$showLeftNavi` doesn't appear to be an observable, so `| async` isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by previous answers async works for observable, but I don't think their answer would work as you want (if you just get rid of the async you'll only get the fist value of the boolean, no matter how many times your observable fired). `this.store.pipe(select(ObservableActions.getNaviState))` is what you want to assign the `async` pipe to like so:

```
$showLeftNavi: Observable<boolean>;

    constructor(private store: Store<StateShared>) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.$showLeftNavi = this.store.pipe(select(ObservableActions.getNaviState));
    }
```

(no change to your html)

Answer (score 0):

The issue I had that brought me to this question was how do I use the async pipe to subscribe to an observable, and have the `*ngIf` evaluate as truthy even when the value evaluates as falsy (eg. the 0 value for an enum).

**Component:**

```
myEnum$: Observable<MyEnum>;

getDescription(enum: MyEnum): void {....}
```

**View:**

```
<div *ngIf="(myEnum$ | async) as myEnum">
    <span> {{getDescription(myEnum)}}</span>    <-- still want this to display when 0
</div>
```

My conclusion is that it is an issue with `*ngIf` with async pipe having two different functions:

- Conditional showing of content
- Subscribing to observables so that the framework manages teardown properly

What I ended up doing was wrapping the enum in an object, so the `*ngIf` evaluates truthy on the object, then unwrapping the enum value to pass to the function.

```
<div *ngIf="(myWrapperObject$ | async) as myWrapperObject">
    <span> {{getDescription(myWrapperObject.enumValue)}} </span>
</div>
```

I'd be interested to know if others know of a better way though.